# Scrapy - extract url within different relative url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract the pdf as well the 10k form (in html format) using Scrapy.
In order to extract them, I am using the following css selector :             `most_recent = response.css("div.view_btn > a::attr(href)").getall()`
which returns `['/Click/29665', '/Click/19504']` as expected.

But the pdf's and html's url is within each relative url.
How can scrapy get the absolute and "correct" url ?

("correct" url = https://www.annualreports.com/HostedData/AnnualReports/PDF/NASDAQ_RMIX_2020.pdf)

I need the url because scrapy sends the response to another function in order to download the pdf files: `yield Request(most_recent, callback=self.save_pdf)`

Thank you in advance !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to simply "calculate" PDF URL. Because when your browser requests `https://www.annualreports.com/Click/10913` the target website response with REDIRECT header `Location: /HostedData/AnnualReports/PDF/NYSE_SMG_2020.pdf` and only after that your browser loads PDF file.

But that's not an issue for Scrapy. Just `yield` your `Click` URL to `save_pdf` callback and it will **automatically** follow redirect for you.

Comment: I've tried this. Unfortunately, it didn't work : 'ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /Click/24604''

+I should also mention that I the page in my question is the last page that the scraper arrives and tries to extract the files

Comment: Of course you need to use `response.urljoin(url)` to get a FULL URL

Comment: Thank you, response.urljoin(url) works totally fine !